# Solve a system of differential equations $\begin{cases} x'=-7x-18y-67e^{-t},x(0)=-1\\ y'=2x+5y+22e^{-t}, \; y(0)=-3 \end{cases}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Apply the operational method to solve the Cauchy problem
$$\begin{cases}
x'=-7x-18y-67e^{-t},x(0)=-1\\
y'=2x+5y+22e^{-t}, \; y(0)=-3
\end{cases}$$

**My attempt:**

$$x(t) = \frac{a \sin(4t)+ b\cos(4t)}{e^{4t}}\overset{x\in [0,1)}{\Rightarrow }x(t) = \frac{a \sin(4t)+ b\cos(4t)}{e^{4t}} + 12$$
It is usually assumed that $x$ is twice differentiable everywhere, so on the boundaries of each of the smooth definitions we need to match the limits $x(0), x(1), x'(0), x'(1)$

$$x(t) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{A\sin(4t)+B\cos(4t)}{e^{4t}},&t<0\\
\frac{C\sin(4t)+D\cos(4t)}{e^{4t}} + 12,&0 < t\le 1\\
\frac{E\sin(4t)+F\cos(4t)}{e^{4t}},&t>1
\end{matrix}\right\}
$$

Then you need to make sure that the initial conditions are met and all boundary conditions are met. $A=2, B=-2, C=-10, D=-14$.

**My solution:**

$$\begin{cases}
x'=-7x-18y-67e^{-t},x(0)=-1\\
y'=2x+5y+22e^{-t}, \; y(0)=-3
\end{cases} \Leftrightarrow \dot{\vec{r}}=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
-7 & -18 \\
2 & 5
\end{array}\right] \vec{r}+\left[\begin{array}{c}
-67 \\
22
\end{array}\right] e^{-t} ; \vec{r}(0)=\left[\begin{array}{l}
-1 \\
-3
\end{array}\right]$$

\begin{multline*}
\mathcal{L}[f(t)]=\int\limits\limits_0^{\infty} f(t) e^{-p t} d t=F(p) \Rightarrow \mathcal{L}\left[\frac{d f}{d t}\right]=\int\limits\limits_0^{\infty} \frac{d f}{d t} e^{-p t} d t=\\=\lim _{t \rightarrow \infty} f(t) e^{-p t}-f(0)+p \int\limits\limits_0^{\infty} f(t) e^{-p t} d t=p F(p)-f(0) 
\end{multline*}
\begin{multline*}
\mathcal{L}[\vec{r}(t)]=\vec{R}(p) \Rightarrow \forall p>-1\left(p \hat{1}-\left[\begin{array}{cc}
-7 & -18 \\
2 & 5
\end{array}\right]\right) \vec{R}(p)=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
p+7 & 18 \\
-2 & p-5
\end{array}\right] \vec{R}(p)=\\=\left[\begin{array}{c}
-1 \\
-3
\end{array}\right]+\left[\begin{array}{c}
-67 \\
22
\end{array}\right] \int\limits\limits_0^{\infty} e^{-(p+1) t} d t=\left[\begin{array}{c}
-1 \\
-3
\end{array}\right]+\frac{1}{p+1}\left[\begin{array}{c}
-67 \\
22
\end{array}\right]=-\frac{1}{p+1}\left[\begin{array}{c}
p+68 \\
3 p-19
\end{array}\right] 
\end{multline*}
\begin{multline*}\left|\begin{array}{cc}
p+7 & 18 \\
-2 & p-5
\end{array}\right|=(p+7)(p-5)+36=p^2+2 p+1=(p+1)^2 \Rightarrow\\\Rightarrow \forall p>-1 \exists\left[\begin{array}{cc}
p+7 & 18 \\
-2 & p-5
\end{array}\right]^{-1}=\frac{1}{(p+1)^2}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
p-5 & -18 \\
2 & p+7
\end{array}\right] \Rightarrow \vec{R}(p)=\\=-\frac{1}{p+1}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
p+7 & 18 \\
-2 & p-5
\end{array}\right]^{-1}\left[\begin{array}{c}
p+68 \\
3 p-19
\end{array}\right]=-\frac{1}{(p+1)^3}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
p-5 & -18 \\
2 & p+7
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
p+68 \\
3 p-19
\end{array}\right]=\\=-\frac{1}{(p+1)^3}\left[\begin{array}{c}
p^2+9 p+2 \\
3 p^2+4 p+3
\end{array}\right]=-\frac{1}{(p+1)^3}\left[\begin{array}{c}
(p+1)^2+7(p+1)-6 \\
3(p+1)^2-2(p+1)+2
\end{array}\right]
\end{multline*}
\begin{multline*}
\mathcal{F}[f(t)]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int\limits\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) e^{-i \omega t} d t \Rightarrow F(p)=\mathcal{L}[f(t)]=\sqrt{2 \pi} \lim _{\omega \rightarrow-i p} \mathcal{F}[f(t) \eta(t)] \Rightarrow\\\Rightarrow f(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}[F(p)]=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int\limits\limits_{\sigma-i \infty}^{\sigma+i \infty} F(p) e^{p t} d p 
\end{multline*}
\begin{multline*}
\left\{z \in \mathbb{C}\left(|z-\sigma| \leq \tau ; \arg (z-\sigma) \in\left[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]\right)\right\}=\Sigma \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint\limits_{\partial \Sigma} F(p) e^{p t} d p=\\=\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\left(\int\limits_{\sigma-i \tau}^{\sigma+i \tau} F(p) e^{p t} d p-i \tau \int\limits_{-\pi / 2}^{\pi / 2} F\left(\sigma+\tau e^{i \varphi}\right) \exp \left(\left(\sigma+\tau e^{i \varphi}\right) t+i \varphi\right) d \varphi\right)=\sum_{s \in\left\{z \in \Sigma \mid F(p) \notin C^1(z)\right\}}\operatorname{Res}\left(F(p) e^{p t}\right)
\end{multline*}
\begin{multline*}
\lim _{\tau \rightarrow \infty} \tau F\left(\sigma+\tau e^{i \varphi}\right)=0 \Rightarrow f(t)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int\limits_{\sigma-i \infty}^{\sigma+i \infty} F(p) e^{p t} d p=\\=\sum_{s \in\left\{z \in \mathbb{C}\left(\operatorname{Re}(z)>\sigma ; F(p) \notin C^1(z)\right)\right\}} \sum_{p=s}\operatorname{Res}\left(F(p) e^{p t}\right)
\end{multline*}
\begin{multline*}
\vec{r}(t)=-\operatorname{Res}_{p=-1}\left(\vec{R}(p) e^{p t}\right)=-\operatorname{Res}_{p=-1}\left(\frac{1}{(p+1)^3}\left[\begin{array}{c}
(p+1)^2+7(p+1)-6 \\
3(p+1)^2-2(p+1)+2
\end{array}\right] e^{p t}\right)=\\=-\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \lim _{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^n}{n !} \oint\limits_{|p+1|=\varepsilon} \frac{p^n}{(p+1)^3}\left[\begin{array}{c}
(p+1)^2+7(p+1)-6 \\
3(p+1)^2-2(p+1)+2
\end{array}\right] d p=\\ =-\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \lim _{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k} C_n^k \frac{t^n}{n !} \oint\limits_{|p+1|=\varepsilon}\left[\begin{array}{c}
(p+1)^{k-1}+7(p+1)^{k-2}-6(p+1)^{k-3} \\
3(p+1)^{k-1}-2(p+1)^{k-2}+2(p+1)^{k-3}
\end{array}\right] d p=\\=-\frac{1}{2 \pi} \lim _{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=k}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-k} C_n^k \frac{t^n}{n !} \varepsilon^{k-2} \int\limits_0^{2 \pi}\left[\begin{array}{c}
\varepsilon^2 e^{2 i \varphi}+7 \varepsilon e^{i \varphi}-6 \\
3 \varepsilon^2 e^{2 i \varphi}-2 \varepsilon e^{i \varphi}+2
\end{array}\right] e^{i(k-2) \varphi} d \varphi=\\ =-\lim _{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=k}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-k} C_n^k \frac{t^n}{n !}\left(\left[\begin{array}{l}
1 \\
3
\end{array}\right] \varepsilon^k \delta_{k 0}+\left[\begin{array}{c}
7 \\
-2
\end{array}\right] \varepsilon^{k-1} \delta_{k 1}+\left[\begin{array}{c}
-6 \\
2
\end{array}\right] \varepsilon^{k-2} \delta_{k 2}\right)=\\=-\left(\left[\begin{array}{l}
1 \\
3
\end{array}\right] \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{t^n}{n !}-\left[\begin{array}{c}
7 \\
-2
\end{array}\right] \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{t^n}{(n-1) !}+\left[\begin{array}{c}
-3 \\
1
\end{array}\right] \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{t^n}{(n-2) !}\right)=\\=\left[\begin{array}{c}
3 t^2-7 t-1 \\
-t^2+2 t-3
\end{array}\right] e^{-t} 
\end{multline*}

Comment: If you have an answer, what exactly is the question here? (The only step I’d add us to explicitly verify the answer.)

Comment: I could only solve the problem a day later) I thought I would get a hint here or a solution sooner

The answer is correct, I checked

Comment: What does **My solution** have to do with the ODE in the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you've already solved it. I think this can be tackled with far more elementary means. I suppose the solution functions $x,y$ are defined on some neighbourhood of zero. From now on, $t$ will refer to a generic element of that neighbourhood.

It follows that $x$ is differentiable twice, indeed: $$x''=-7x'-18(2x+5y+22e^{-t})+67e^{-t}=-7x'-329e^{-t}-36x-5(-7x-67e^{-t}-x')$$Simplifying: $$x''+2x'+x=6e^{-t}$$The auxiliary equation has a double root at $-1$ so the complementary function shall be $(At+B)e^{-t}$ for some arbitrary constants $A$ and $B$ and the particular integral needs to be $3t^2e^{-t}$ after some basic computation.

So: $$x(t)=(B+At+3t^2)e^{-t}\\y=\frac{1}{18}(-7x-x'-67e^{-t})=-\frac{1}{18}(67+6B+A+6(1+A)t+24t^2)e^{-t}$$

Initial conditions: $x(0)=-1=B$, $-3=y(0)=-\frac{1}{18}(67+6B+A)=-\frac{1}{18}(61+A)$ hence $A=-7$. Together that gives: $$x(t)=(3t^2-7t-1)e^{-t},\,y(t)=-\frac{1}{18}(54-36t+18t^2)e^{-t}=(2t-t^2-3)e^{-t}$$