# Solve differential equation $x''+8x'+32x=\begin{cases} 384,\; t\in [0,1), \; x(0)=-2\\ 0,\; t\notin [0,1), \; x'(0)=16 \end{cases}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve differential equation
> $$x''+8x'+32x=\begin{cases}
> 384,\; t\in [0,1), \; x(0)=-2\\
> 0,\; t\notin [0,1), \; x'(0)=16
> \end{cases}$$

I have already solved a similar problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4706632/solve-a-system-of-differential-equations-begincases-x-7x-18y-67e-t-x0). I also tried to solve this equation above through the Laplace transform, but it doesn’t work. I can't figure out what $t$ refers to and how to solve this equation under these conditions

Comment: Equations of this form can be handled more easily than Laplace transforms would suggest. Obtain a general solution on $(0,1)$ and a general solution on $\Bbb R\setminus[0,1]$, try to setup the constants to that the two solutions glue together correctly on the boundary $\{0,1\}$

Answer (score 0):

I suppose $t$ represents the independent variable ($x=x(t)$). You can plug in the solution $ x=Ae^{at} =A\exp \left (at\right )$. Then, you'll have $$ Ae^{at}\left (a^{2} +8a +32\right )=\begin{cases}
384,\; t\in [0,1), \; x(0)=-2\\
0,\; t\notin [0,1), \; x'(0)=16
\end{cases}$$
Now you have $a^{2} +8a +32 =0$, when $0,\; t\notin [0,1), \; x'(0)=16$, and $a^{2} +8a -352 =0$, when  $t\in [0,1), \; x(0)=-2\\$.
Finally, solve the quadratics equations to find $a$ in each case, and then use the initial conditions to find A.